# Как прочитать XML файлы в папке и вывести разный текст в ToolTip?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть форма на форме есть несколько TextBoxов с ToolTip-ами. И есть папка с XML файлами выглядят они так

Файл A.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Root><Statya><Termin>Австралия</Termin></Statya><Statya><Termin>Африка</Termin></Statya><Root>
```

Файл B.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Root><Statya><Termin>Бельгия</Termin></Statya><Statya><Termin>Болгария</Termin></Statya><Root>
```

Как правильно прочитать эти файлы в папке и в Content ToolTip подставить из этих файлов разный текст по позиции?

Т. е. есть первый TextBox в его ToolTip вывести Австралия, есть другие TextBox и в его ToolTip вывести Бельгия и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала извлекаем данные из файл в коллекцию с помощью LINQ:

```
XElement main = XElement.Load(@"from.xml");

var terms = main
    .Descendants("Statya")
    .Descendants("Termin")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Теперь, когда в коллекции хранится список строк со значениями элементов, устанавливаем значения подсказок для коллекции ToolTip'ов.

```
// Выполнить для каждой подсказки
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    tooltips[i].Content = terms[i]; 
}
```

где tooltips - это коллекция подсказок для тех контролов, который надо обновить.