# Как выводить каждую следующую запись из XML в TextBox?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть несколько XML файлов, выглядят они так:

A.xml

```
<Root>
    <Statya>
        <Termin>Австралия</Termin>
    </Statya>
    <Statya>
        <Termin>Австрия</Termin>
    </Statya>
</Root>
```

B.xml

```
<Root>
    <Statya>
        <Termin>Будапешт</Termin>
    </Statya>
    <Statya>
        <Termin>Болгария</Termin>
    </Statya>
</Root>
```

и т.д.

Как сделать переход на следующую и предыдущую запись в этих файлах при нажатии кнопки и выводить каждую следующую, первую, предыдущую и последнюю запись в TextBox?

Пробовал вывести так, но не работает: выводит запись на букву C, а не на A, и не первую запись

```
int i = 1;
string jmm;

private void moveNextStatya_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List <string> fbv = new List<string> () {"A.xml", "B.xml", "C.xml"};

    foreach(string gfc in fbv) {
        jmm = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + @"" + gfc;

        if (File.Exists(jmm)) {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(jmm);

            XmlNode currNode = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
            i++;
            XmlNode nextNode = currNode.NextSibling.SelectSingleNode("//Root/Statya[position()='" + i + "']/Termin");
            XmlNode nextNode2 = currNode.SelectSingleNode("//Root/Statya[position()=last()]/Termin");

            if (nextNode != null) {
                if (nextNode.InnerText == nextNode2.InnerText) {
                    text5.Text = nextNode2.InnerText;
                } else if (nextNode.InnerText != nextNode2.InnerText) {
                    text5.Text = nextNode.InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вдобавок к [предыдущему ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82532#82583).

```
string[] files = { "A.xml", "B.xml", "C.xml" };
Dictionary<string, string[]> values = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
int current = 0;

// Загрузка словарей из файлов
foreach (string file in files)
{
    XElement main = XElement.Load(file);

    var terms = main
        .Descendants("Statya")
        .Descendants("Termin")
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToArray();

    values[file] = terms;
}

// Движение вперед
current++;

// Движение назад
current--;

// Вывод значений, словарь контролов уже должен быть сформирован
foreach (string file in files)
{
    textbox[file].Text = values[file][current];
}
```

Comment: А как сформировать словарь контролов?

Comment: Этот код не совсем правильно работает. Переход на следующий осуществляется но вместо файла A.xml при нажатии на кнопку загружается файл C.xml.